# Local Notifications in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

This is my code

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.localNotifications.schedule({    // ionic local notification native plugin.
        title: 'Welcome',
        text: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000)
      })
    })
```

When use the `at:` variable I get the error as

> Argument of type ‘{ title: any; text: string; at: Date; }’ is not
>   assignable to parameter of type ‘ILocalNotification |
>   ILocalNotification’. Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and ‘at’ does not exist in type ‘ILocalNotification |
>   ILocalNotification’.

I want to prompt the notification after 1 sec. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options object is not match with local-notifications options kindly review this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/. Here you can find the all the options. For schedule 1 second delay local-notification you can modify code like this.

```
 this.localNotifications.schedule({
   title: 'Welcome',
   text: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000)},
   });
```

Hope you find your solutions.